# Windows 7 Freezes on Boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

I have a HP ProBook 4530s running Windows 7 SP1 that will not boot when I try to turn it on.
After about 20 seconds of Starting Windows the entire system freezes. The disk activity light turns of as well as the pulsating Windows logo.
I’ve tried Automatic repair, CHKDSK twice, System Restore twice and running different BIOS diagnostics tools. The only way I can get it to boot is by running it in safe mode. I don’t want to reinstall Windows.
Then last thing it loaded was ‘\systemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\USBSTOR.SYS’
EDIT: It has also been left overnight to boot.